# Using scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs to find when the eigenvalue real part crosses zero

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, eigenvalue

I am using [`scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs) to calculate the eigenvalues of a large sparse matrix, which is a Jacobian for a vector function (the Jacobian size is 1200x1200). The method raises [`ArpackNoConvergence`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.ArpackNoConvergence.html) every once in a while, and I think it happens especially when the real part of the eigenvalues become small in magnitude (but still negative). How can I set this method to be able to calculate those eigenvalues without crashing?

My current setup is:

```
eigs = sparse.linalg.eigs(jacobian(state),k=1,which='LR',return_eigenvectors=False)[0]
```

What I would like to achieve is to find when the real part of one of the eigenvalues crosses zero (and thus the state is unstable linearly).

Comment: probably a silly idea, but if it's really the real parts of the eigenvalues, can't you just shift them by adding a multiple of the identity matrix?

Comment: Well, I haven't thought about it so I would say it is the most silly idea, assuming that I am not the most silly person :) ... anyway, so if I add a certain multiple of the identity matrix I shift the real part of all eigenvalues by the same constant, right? And this should make the algorithm find the highest real value more easily?

Comment: The shifting bit should work for any scalar real  or complex. Whether it helps the algorithm I don't know. You'll have to try.